# Animating organisms motion with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, motion

I am trying to create an organism evolution simulation with python. I have just started, so I am only at the very beginnig and I already failed miserably.

I have created the class for organism and the functions for plotting organisms and plotting the frames as well.

I have created already a very basic "motion" of the organism, but instead of getting to see the "movement" I get the final image displaying all the stages of the motion on one image. I have tried to place plt.show and sleep everywhere, but no awail.

Could you please and give me some hints where I should be putting (or what should I be changing) in order to make it work?

the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import uniform

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.lines as lines

from math import sin
from math import cos
from math import radians

from matplotlib.patches import Circle


settings={
    "max_x":300,
    "min_x":0,
    "max_y":300,
    "min_y":0,
    
    "v_max":0.5,
    
    "pop_size":1
    
}    

class organism:
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.x=uniform(settings['min_x'], settings['max_x'])
        self.y=uniform(settings['min_y'], settings['max_y'])
        
        self.r=uniform(0,360) #irány
        self.v=uniform(0,0.5)
        
    def move(self):
        self.x=self.x+5
        
    


def plot_organism(x1,y1,theta,ax):
    circle=Circle([x1,y1], 10, edgecolor='g', facecolor='lightgreen', zorder=8)
    ax.add_artist(circle)
    
    edge=Circle([x1,y1], 10, facecolor='None', edgecolor='darkgreen', zorder=8)
    ax.add_artist(edge)
    
    tail_len=0.075
    
    x2=cos(radians(theta))*tail_len+x1
    y2=sin(radians(theta))*tail_len+y1
    
    ax.add_line(lines.Line2D([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color='darkgreen', linewidth=1, zorder=10))
    
    pass

def plot_frame(settings, organisms,fig,ax):
    
    
    plt.xlim(settings["min_x"]*1.25, settings['max_x']*1.25)
    plt.ylim(settings["min_y"]*1.25, settings['max_y']*1.25)
    
    for organism in organisms:
        plot_organism(organism.x,organism.y,organism.r,ax)
        
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    frame = plt.gca()
    
        
        
def simulate(total_time, organisms):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(9.6,5.4)
    
    total_time_step=total_time
    
    for t_step in range(0,total_time_step):
        plot_frame(settings,organisms,fig,ax)
        
        
        for organism in organisms:
            organism.move()
            
    sleep(0.5)
    plt.show()
    
        
    return organisms
        
def run(settings):

    organisms=[]
    for i in range(0,settings["pop_size"]):
        organisms.append(organism(settings))
        
    simulate(10, organisms)
 
    
    pass

run(settings)
```

the output I am getting:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to make the simulation based on [this/][2]

Thank you in advance for your help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbn4.png
[2]: https://nathanrooy.github.io/posts/2017-11-30/evolving-simple-organisms-using-a-genetic-algorithm-and-deep-learning/

Comment: Read the `matplotlib` docs on how to create animations.

Comment: hey matt...really helpful here..thank you..duh..

Comment: I'm not sure what else you want. This isn't a tutorial site, and you haven't attempted to use the animation capabilities present in `matplotlib`. [This part of the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) would be a great place to start. You probably want to look at [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html#funcanimation) first.